# В массиве выводится мусор (Задача на нахождение одинаковых элементов в динамических массивах)

Tags: c++

Дано два динамических массива одинаковой размерности. Нужно вывести массив с одинаковыми элементами этих массивов. В итоге делает размерность исходных массивов, заносит одинаковое число, а на остальные места мусор. Помогите найти ошибку:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    void Mas(int** mas1, int** mas2, int &n)
{
    cin >> n;
    *mas1 = new int[n];
    *mas2 = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*mas1)[i] = rand() % 10;

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        (*mas2)[j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

    void PrintMas1(int* mas1, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            cout << mas1[i] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

        void PrintMas2( int* mas2, int n){
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << mas2[j] << '\t';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

        void Same(int** mas1, int** mas2, int&n) {
            int Sam = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    if ((*mas1)[i] == (*mas2)[j]) {
                        Sam++;
                    }
                }
            }
            int *newMas = new int[Sam];
            int Move = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n-Sam; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n-Sam; j++)
                    if ((*mas1)[i] == (*mas2)[j]) {
                        newMas[Move] = (*mas1)[i];
                        Move++;
                    }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                cout << newMas[i] << '\t';
            }
            cout << endl;
            delete[](newMas);

        }



    int main () {
        int n = 0;
        int *mas1 = NULL;
        int *mas2 = NULL;
        Mas(&mas1, &mas2, n);
        PrintMas1(mas1, n);
        PrintMas2(mas2, n);
        Same(&mas1, &mas2, n);
        delete[] mas1;
        delete[] mas2;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: масив `newMas` надо занулить перед использованием. Тогда будет не мусор, а нули

Comment: Да, верно, нужно newMas обнулить перед использованием: просто делаете цикл, который присваивает всем значениям 0. И еще: зачем вам две функции print? Они обе делают ровно одно и то же!

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, цикл делать не обязательно, поставьте круглые скобки в конце - `int *newMas = new int[Sam]();`.

Comment: @GreenDragon я этого и не знал)

Answer (score 0):

Ты сначала считаешь кол-во одинаковых элементов, для создание массива, но затем ты зачем-то приходишься только по n-Sam элементам твоих массивов. То есть если у тебя два массива {5 7 8 9 1} и {6 2 1 7 5}, то ты создаешь третий массив размером в 3, а затем приходишься по первым трем элементам первых двух массивов то есть {5 7 8} и {6 2 1}, как видно здесь нет одинаковых элементов, а так как ты не обнулил третий массив том остался мусор.